# CSR 8670 Dual mode Bluetooth showing two icons on Apple Devices

Tags: bluetooth

I am developing a dual Bluetooth device on the CSR8670 with ADK 4.0.1.

On IOS Devices, my device shows up as "Two icons" in the Bluetooth device list.  I want only one icon.  Devices such as the Jabra sports earphones do this.

I have found by mistake that corrupting the Advertising packet can do this, but it is not the proper solution.

Comment: if your device is v4.1 or below, there is no cross transport pairing supported and hence they need to be paired twice for each transport. 
if your device is v4.2 then one pairing is sufficient to make it work ( as the link key can be translated to an LTK and vise versa).  I would assume android also shows two devices one belong to Bluetooth Classic and another LE?

Comment: Android only shows one device.  IOS shows two devices.  I believe that the chip can work as Two seperate bluetooth devices, or a Dual mode device.  I believe it is working like two devices, rather than one.  I am not sure if the ADK 4.0.1 is using Bluetooth 4.1 or 4.2? I need to check with CSR.

Comment: Me too, still did not see iOS doing that corrently. We use a CSR8670 as well. On Android CTKD is working from BLE to BR/EDR. The chip is not capable of doing CTKD from BR/EDR to BLE. Only the CSR8675 is. Nevertheless, on iOS I did not see it working ...